# C programming interview question about dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

If you want to allocated 8 bytes of memory dynamically in the heap but this 8 bytes of memory is not available continuously. It is available as 5 bytes and 3 bytes separately in the heap. Then can you allocate the memory? if yes, how?

If yes, Can we use only malloc or malloc with calloc

Comment: In general, if you need to allocate a single object you need the memory to be contiguous. So the answer is no.

Comment: 8 bytes of memory not being contiguously available on the heap is a pretty niche corner case. A 5 byte block and a 3 byte block being available strikes me as even more niche.

Comment: Sounds like a trick question to me. I'd run away from that place.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Also completely irrelevant to writing portable, maintainable C code.  Either `malloc()` *et al* return a valid pointer or the return `NULL` and there's little you can to but accept the results and handle them.  If they're happy with any answer other than "Bogus, trick question!", yeah, run away from that place.  **FAR, FAR away**.  OP:  Please include links to this question in your answer.  :-)

Comment: Interview questions quite often invite a **discussion** rather than a definite answer. They don't need an answer, but they do need to test your knowledge. If you should keep repeating something like "trick question" or in another case  "undefined behaviour", you are not giving them what they are looking for. Interviews (and examination questions) are not about two-word answers.

Comment: ... for example, you might say "if memory is in such short supply, then `malloc` probably isn't appropriate, but the available memory should be carefully mapped to the usage required."

Answer (score 6):

The granularity of the heap is typically 8 or 16 bytes.  It is rather unlikely that there be 2 blocks available for respectively 5 and 3 bytes and neither of them be available for an allocation of 8 bytes.  If memory is so scarce you encounter this situation and allocating an 8 byte block with `malloc()` or `calloc()` fails, you should not try to handle the requirement with 2 separate blocks, but rather signal an out of memory condition and handle it gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to allocated 8 bytes of memory dynamically in the heap but this 8 bytes of memory is not available continuously.
> It is available as 5 bytes and 3 bytes separately in the heap.
> Then can you allocate the memory?

Each successful call to `malloc()` (or `calloc()`) allocates a *contiguous* block of memory.  If there is no large enough block available then `malloc()` (`calloc()`) will fail.  `malloc()` does not have any way to return discontinuous memory blocks.  And it must not move allocated blocks, so it cannot coalesce blocks that are not already contiguous.

So, can you allocate an 8-byte chunk? No, you cannot.

Can you allocate two chunks, with a combined size of 8 bytes?  If we understand the question as asserting that a 5-byte chunk and a separate 3-byte chunk can be allocated separately, then yes: that is stipulated by the question.  If that's what is actually being asked, then the underlying issue is probably how you can *discover* that the 5-byte and 3-byte chunks are available.  There is no memory-introspection mechanism by which you could look for a combination of available blocks, but you could simply try smaller and smaller sizes until you find one that works, and then see whether you can allocate the remainder.  For example:

```
void allocate8(void **ret1, void **ret2) {
    void *p1 = NULL;
    void *p2 = NULL;

    for (int i = 8; i >= 4; i--) {
        p1 = malloc(i);
        if (p1) {
            if (i < 8) {
                p2 = malloc(8 - i);
                if (!p2) {
                    free(p1);
                    p1 = NULL;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    *ret1 = p1;
    *ret2 = p2;
}
```

But is that *useful*?  Almost surely not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the problem you described, it concerns memory fragmentation. Unfortunately as a developer you can't remedy this especially being limited to only malloc() and calloc() functions, the best you can do is be aware of the problem and try to catch it. The solution to the problem depends on the memory allocator used in the system.